# How to Align a Select Element and Button Element

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the select element and the button, but could not succeed. I tried the following code:

echo "

```
         <select class='form-select form-select-sm' id='tstatus' name='tstatus'>
         <option selected value='$status'>Status</option>
         <option value='Booked'>Booked</option>
         <option value='Ontrip'>On Trip</option>
         <option value='Cancelled'>Cancelled</option>


         </select>
         <input type='hidden' class='form-control' id='tid' name='tid' value='$id'> 
         <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'  name='thestatus' id='thestatus'  value='Go'>

         </form>
         </td>";
         

          </td>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"align"_? Also, why do you have `</td>` at the end of `</form>`? Kindly update the code and explain what you want properly.

Comment: By Align, I mean, keeping the button in line

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? You've tagged `bootstrap-4` but you're using classes from `bootstrap-5`.

Comment: I have used Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap, you can wrap the `select` and the `button` in a div with a class of `input-group`. Try this

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="tstatus" name="tstatus">
         <option selected value="$status">Status</option>
         <option value="Booked">Booked</option>
         <option value="Ontrip">On Trip</option>
         <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="tid" name="tid" value="$id"> <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="thestatus" id="thestatus"  value="Go">
</div>
```